# Porting python CVXPY code to R CVXR

Tags: r

I am trying to learn how the CVXR package works, and I was porting a
 Python example
 by Steve Diamond here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cvxpy/5hBSB9KVbuI
  and
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/cvxgrp/cvx_short_course/blob/master/intro/control.ipynb

The R equivalent of the code is below:

```
set.seed(1)
n = 8
m = 2
T1 = 50
alpha = 0.2
beta = 5
A = diag(n) + alpha*replicate(n, rnorm(n))
B = replicate(m, rnorm(n))
x_0 = beta*replicate(1, rnorm(n))

# Form and solve control problem.
x = Variable(n, T1+1)
u = Variable(m, T1)

states = c()
for (t in 1:T1) {
   cost = sum_squares(x[,t+1]) + sum_squares(u[,t])
   constr = list(x[, t+1] == A%*%x[, t] + B%*%u[, t],
      norm_inf(u[,t]) <= 1)
   states = c(states, Problem(Minimize(cost), constr) )
}
# sums problem objectives and concatenates constraints.
prob <- Reduce("+", states)
constraints(prob) <- c(constraints(prob), x[ ,T1] == 0)
constraints(prob) <- c(constraints(prob), x[ ,0] == x_0)
sol <- solve(prob)
```

I have a challenge with the second-to-last line (it throws an error):

`constraints(prob) <- c(constraints(prob), x[ ,0] == x_0)`

My guess is that `x[ , 0]` points to the zero-th index position of the
 variable, `x`, which does not exist in R. But from Python which the
 program is converted from, a zero-th index position exists from the
 `for` loop (for t in range(T)). `range(T)` is a vector starting from 0
 - 49.
 But in R, the `for` loop (`for (t in 1:T1)` ) is for a vector of 1 - 50.

Please, any ideas  to help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `x[, 0]` with `x[, 1]`? `x` has `T1 + 1` columns, so it seems like this should work.

Comment: Yes, but it makes the optimization solution infeasible and the resulting values are all NAs.  But this is not the case with its Python equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bump up the index number by 1, so `x[,1] == x_0` and `x[,T1+1] == 0` in the second and third from the last line, respectively. Otherwise, you never set the `T1+1` entry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes you're right, but yet the optimization solution is *infeasible* and the resulting values are all NAs. I now have the last three lines of code as:


     `constraints(prob) <- c(constraints(prob), x[ , T1+1] == 0)`

     `constraints(prob) <- c(constraints(prob), x[ , 1] == x_0)`

      `sol <- solve(prob)`

I am yet wondering what I could be doing incorrectly for this behavior as the result doesn't match Python's

Comment: I find that setting the solver to "SCS" yields a solution with status "optimal_inaccurate". That is:

`constraints(prob) <- c(constraints(prob), x[ , 1] == x_0);`
`constraints(prob) <- c(constraints(prob), x[ , T1 + 1] == 0);`
`sol1 <- solve(prob, solver = "SCS");`